# SonarQube and checking for literal strings

Tags: java, javascript, sonarqube

I'm looking at the SonarQube product for use on a project,  and we have a historical  issue in making sure that all literal strings are pushed out to a resource file ready for internationalization.

Does the SonarQube regime include any checks to find literal strings that should be moved to a resource file?  Our tech stack is Java and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a feature. This would require a specific check that knows what string should or should not be localized - for instance like what's done on Eclipse plugin when using the `//$NON-NLS-x$` comment.

Comment: Does this feature introduced in the latest version of sonarqube?